# Code Metric Tools for Haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there any tool for measuring the code metrics like LOC(line of code), number of functions and average size of functions for Haskell programs?

Comment: If you are also interested in making metrics for style/quality, you might want to check out hlint (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hlint).

Comment: “average size of functions” is a bit of a problematic quantity: a considerable fraction of all lines in the functions I write are themselves function definitions...

Answer (score 2):

[Ohcount](https://github.com/blackducksw/ohcount), the tool used by [ohloh](https://github.com/blackducksw/ohcount), at least knows how to tell Haskell comment lines from Haskell code lines apart, as you can see for example in the [statistics for GHC](http://www.ohloh.net/p/ghc/analyses/latest/languages_summary).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the mentioned HLint for code style checking, there are not that many mature tools as in other language ecosystems. I would point out the following tools in development:

- [homplexity](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/homplexity): this project "aims to assess complexity and quality of Haskell code by measuring relative length of declarations, their depth, and code-to-comment ratio".
- [argon](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/argon): it computes cyclomatic complexity.

Comment: And this project is also relevant to measuring code quality: [dead-code-detection](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dead-code-detection).

Answer (score 0):

When Joost Visser (http://www.cs.ru.nl/J.Visser/) was a member of the PURe research group (http://wiki.di.uminho.pt/twiki/bin/view/Research/PURe/WebHome) at the Universidade do Minho the group produced a number of libraries for deriving metrics and documented the work in research papers.

I don't think the code every made it to Hackage, but the SVN server may still be active. I believe they had some code for extracting Haskell metrics, I'm not sure it was ever a significant focus - the code to extract metrics from grammars (SdfMetz) was written in Haskell. Idiomatically Haskell tends to be quite terse which is rather contrary to the explanatory value of metrics.